# How do you make an entire control clickable in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

I have a custom control in android that has a text view, some images, etc.

**I want to make the entire control clickable.**

I declared the layout with:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
```

even though it has that android:clickable attribute set to true, the click event never fires.

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In your Main Activity code , do something like this

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements
    OnTouchListener, OnLongClickListener, OnKeyListener,
    OnClickListener, OnFocusChangeListener{

CustomUI = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.custom_ui);

    CustomUI.addListener(this);
    CustomUI.setOnClickListener(this); 
    CustomUI.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    CustomUI.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    CustomUI.setOnTouchListener(this);
    CustomUI.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

`}`

Also you can't put attributes in your Relative layout , you have to include your custom ui it this layout ... something like

```
<RelativeLayout

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

 <com.company.some.CustomView

        android:id="@+id/custom_ui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

  </RelativeLayout>
```